# Как парсить с параметрами relationships?

Tags: python, html, парсер, parse

Есть многоуровневый список на сайте. Ниже пример зависимости:

```json
"included": [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "type": "cmp",
    "attributes": {
      "name": "Микропрограммное обеспечение",
      "identifier": "К.1.1",
      "parent_id": null,
      "cmpt_id": "1"
    },
    "relationships": {
      "childs": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "2",
            "type": "cmp"
          },
          {
            "id": "3",
            "type": "cmp"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "type": "cmp",
    "attributes": {
      "name": "Прошивка (встроенная микропрограмма)",
      "identifier": "К.1.1.1",
      "parent_id": "1",
      "cmpt_id": "1"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "type": "cmp",
    "attributes": {
      "name": "UEFI/BIOS",
      "identifier": "К.1.1.2",
      "parent_id": "1",
      "cmpt_id": "1"
    }
  }
]
```

Как можно спарсить данные так, чтобы в первом столбце были дочерние значения, а во втором соответствующие повторяющиеся родительские значения?